# Guidance needed to understand quaternion and movetowards of gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I am trying to move a game object in 3d space I have searched the internet and found there are 3 ways to do that using turntoface(euler angles) or quaternion or navmesh agents

My problem is the game object default rotation is changing in using quaternions or move towards.

Can anyone help me understand why it is happening like that.

I want the capsule in slanted position.

```
//below code is using quaternions
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Guard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5;
    public float waitTime = .3f;
    public float turnSpeed = 90;
    public Transform pathHolder;
    public Transform target;
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3[] waypoints = new Vector3[pathHolder.childCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
        {
            waypoints = pathHolder.GetChild(i).position;
            waypoints = new Vector3(waypoints.x, transform.position.y, waypoints.z);
        }
        StartCoroutine(FollowPath(waypoints));
    }
    IEnumerator FollowPath(Vector3[] waypoints)
    {
        transform.position = waypoints[0];
        int targetWaypointIndex = 1;
        Vector3 targetWaypoint = waypoints[targetWaypointIndex];
        while (true)
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetWaypoint - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            if (transform.rotation == targetRotation)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetWaypoint, speed * Time.deltaTime);
                if (transform.position == targetWaypoint)
                {
                    targetWaypointIndex = (targetWaypointIndex + 1) % waypoints.Length;
                    targetWaypoint = waypoints[targetWaypointIndex];
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
                }
            }
            yield return null;
        }
        IEnumerator TurnToFace(Vector3 lookTarget)
        {
            Vector3 dirToLookTarget = (lookTarget - transform.position).normalized;
            float targetAngle = 90 - Mathf.Atan2(dirToLookTarget.y, dirToLookTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            while (Mathf.Abs(Mathf.DeltaAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle)) > 0.05f)
            {
                float angle = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * angle;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
            Vector3 startPosition = pathHolder.GetChild(0).position;
            Vector3 previousPosition = startPosition;
            foreach (Transform waypoint in pathHolder)
            {
                Gizmos.DrawSphere(waypoint.position, .3f);
                Gizmos.DrawLine(previousPosition, waypoint.position);
                previousPosition = waypoint.position;
            }
            Gizmos.DrawLine(previousPosition, startPosition);
        }
    }
}

    

    //below code is using turntoface (euler angles concept)
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    public class Guard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5;
    public float waitTime = .3f;
    public float turnSpeed = 90;
    public Transform pathHolder;
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3[] waypoints = new Vector3[pathHolder.childCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
        {
            waypoints = pathHolder.GetChild(i).position;
            waypoints = new Vector3(waypoints.x, transform.position.y, waypoints.z);
        }
        StartCoroutine(FollowPath(waypoints));
    }
    IEnumerator FollowPath(Vector3[] waypoints)
    {
        transform.position = waypoints[0];
        int targetWaypointIndex = 1;
        Vector3 targetWaypoint = waypoints[targetWaypointIndex];
        transform.LookAt(targetWaypoint);
        while (true)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetWaypoint, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            if (transform.position == targetWaypoint)
            {
                targetWaypointIndex = (targetWaypointIndex + 1) % waypoints.Length;
                targetWaypoint = waypoints[targetWaypointIndex];
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
                yield return StartCoroutine(TurnToFace(targetWaypoint));
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator TurnToFace(Vector3 lookTarget)
    {
        Vector3 dirToLookTarget = (lookTarget - transform.position).normalized;
        float targetAngle = 90 - Mathf.Atan2(dirToLookTarget.z, dirToLookTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        while (Mathf.DeltaAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle) > 0.05f)
        {
            float angle = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * angle;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Vector3 startPosition = pathHolder.GetChild(0).position;
        Vector3 previousPosition = startPosition;
        foreach (Transform waypoint in pathHolder)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(waypoint.position, .3f);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(previousPosition, waypoint.position);
            previousPosition = waypoint.position;
        }
        Gizmos.DrawLine(previousPosition, startPosition);
    }
}
```

[This link has all videos and required output for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I0iK.jpg)

Comment: Any chance you could format your code?  It's kinda hard to read.  Also why post all the commented-out code?

Comment: Ouch. So a half page of comments and half page of zero formatted code?  Ok. A navmesh agent tells something how to get to a position. It will turn to face that direction. If you set your capsule at an angle inside another gameobject which is the agent. Your capsule will remain at an angle. Whatever all that code does. Sounds overkill.

Comment: I have put two types of code in the question commented one is using quaternions and normal code is using movetowards.

Comment: @BugFinder I understand that regarding navmesh agent but I want to do that using quaternions and my turntoface as soon as those lines get executed my capsule is losing it's default rotation and gets aligned with axes.

Comment: As I said. Put the capsule  as a sub object so you can turn and twist it what ever way you want. If you are turning the object. The navmesh is basically irrelevant to this question.